# Edit multiple list items in one shot?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, list-item, updatelistitems

I have a list that contains many items.  I'd like to give my users the ability to select 10-20 items by "checking" them and then edit them all at once.  Certain fields (item name, id, etc.) are item-specific and should not be edited, but other field values can be specified in bulk.

If I check one item, the "Edit Item" button is active, but as soon as I select 2 items, it is disabled.  How can I add this feature to my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not available OOB...

What you can do is [create a new Custom Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh500259.aspx) that will add a button to the ribbon right after the Edit button.

In custom action, call a Javascript function in which you can get all the items selected by user, see [this URL](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/forum/sharepoint-2010-programming/get-selected-items-in-a-list-sharepoint-2010/).

and then redirect the user to a web part page or open Modal pop up dialog [sending selected items as query string with separator] with the web part page, inside the web part page drop a Visual Web Part and you need to code the Visual Web Part as well...

Inside the Visual Web Part you can update all the selected items with the Title and other fields given by user :)

I hope this helps, a lot of coding and customization involved...

Comment: Just want to add a link to a codeplex project that does something like this, maybe it fit the requirements: http://sp2010batchedit.codeplex.com/

Comment: Anders, thanks for pointing to the CodePlex project...!

Comment: Thank you Arsalan, I'm comfortable with the custom coding.  I've done each component of this for other things so I will put them together as you've described.  Thanks again ;)

Comment: mikey, no problem - Always there to help :)

Comment: This is ridiculous.  You can't edit multiple selected items?  Of course not!  Why on EARTH would anyone want to do that???

Answer (score 2):

XsltListViewWebPart supports inline editing: check the Allow Inline Editing checkbox on the Edit View page. Maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a list where I needed to edit multiple items and used the following process to get it done;
Select the list view from the toolbar ribbon and then select Datasheet view from the submenu items.
This will convert your view to an excel like spread sheet. Sort the columns and then sort by the column you want to edit to have the target cells listed sequentially.
Change the first cell to the new value and then drag copy that cell down the list to all the others you want to edit.